# moments JS - correct way to compare local time

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I'm trying to use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com) to compare a date stored in the database (which is set to `Europe/London` timezone) against the current users time, taking into account their timezone.

I get a date string returned from the database and want to use the `fromNow()` function, as follows:

```
console.log(dbDate);
console.log(moment().format());
console.log(moment(dbDate).fromNow());

// DB stored time (Europe/London)
// 2017-09-26 06:56:26

// Current user time (timezone is Pacific Time / Los Angeles)
// 2017-09-25T23:59:03-07:00

// String output by fromNow() function, which should reflect the timezone difference but doesn't
// in 7 hours
```

I want the `fromNow()` string to take account the timezone difference and this should always be a time `"ago"` as opposed to in the future.

I'm probably missing something quite obvious with the library, so apologies in advance if this is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
// get the current time so we know which offset to take
var now = moment.utc();
// get the zone offsets for this time, in minutes
var NewYork_tz_offset = moment.tz.zone("America/New_York").offset(now); 
var MY_DATE = moment(dbDate);
// calculate the difference in hours
console.log((NewYork_tz_offset - MY_DATE) / 60);
```

Does this help your cause?

Comment: Thanks. I won't know the user timezone, so I need to detect it, but applying your code with the following doesn't work as expected `var NewYork_tz_offset = moment.tz.zone(moment.tz.guess()).offset(now);` - any ideas?

Comment: It's UTC i believe (using Magento)

Comment: You need to convert both of them in a single format and just subtract the difference. You'll get the value in seconds. Which you can convert in hours or any format you like.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [moment timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/), you can parse `dbDate` specifying `"Europe/London"` timezone using [`moment.tz`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/):

> The `moment.tz` constructor takes all the same arguments as the moment constructor, but uses the last argument as a time zone identifier.

Then you can use moment [`diff`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) and [`fromNow`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/).

Here a live example:

```js
var dbDate = "2017-09-26 06:56:26";
var now = moment();
var momDbDate = moment.tz(dbDate, "Europe/London");
var pacificTime = moment("2017-09-25T23:59:03-07:00");
console.log(dbDate);
console.log(moment().format());
console.log(momDbDate.fromNow());
console.log(momDbDate.diff(now, 'hours'));
console.log(momDbDate.diff(pacificTime, 'hours'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.13/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```